# Numpy: Fastest way of computing diagonal for each row of a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a 2d Numpy array, I would like to be able to compute the diagonal for each row in the fastest way possible, I'm right now using a list comprehension but I'm wondering if it can be vectorised somehow?

For example using the following *M* array:

```py
M = np.random.rand(5, 3)


[[ 0.25891593  0.07299478  0.36586996]
 [ 0.30851087  0.37131459  0.16274825]
 [ 0.71061831  0.67718718  0.09562581]
 [ 0.71588836  0.76772047  0.15476079]
 [ 0.92985142  0.22263399  0.88027331]]
```

I would like to compute the following array:

```py
np.array([np.diag(row) for row in M])

array([[[ 0.25891593,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.07299478,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.36586996]],

       [[ 0.30851087,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.37131459,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.16274825]],

       [[ 0.71061831,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.67718718,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.09562581]],

       [[ 0.71588836,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.76772047,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.15476079]],

       [[ 0.92985142,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.22263399,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.88027331]]])
```

Comment: There may be a good reason that you need all of those diagonal matrices, but for large `n` you'll be wasting a whole bunch of space. I don't know what you're doing that would make diagonal matrices preferable over a vector containing the same information, but you might want to see if there is a way to do it with the compact representation of your data.

Comment: I'm implementing a vectorised form of Von Kries chromatic adaptation transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Kries_Coefficient_Law#von_Kries_Transform

Comment: Sure, so in the end if all you need is multiplication of a matrix by a diagonal matrix, that's the same as broadcasting multiplication of a vector by a matrix. Though since your matrices will only ever be 3 columns wide, you aren't wasting *too* much space. Just a thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the good answer of @ajcr, a much faster alternative can be achieved with fancy indexing (tested in NumPy 1.9.0):

```
import numpy as np

def sol0(M):
    return np.eye(M.shape[1]) * M[:,np.newaxis,:]

def sol1(M):
    b = np.zeros((M.shape[0], M.shape[1], M.shape[1]))
    diag = np.arange(M.shape[1])
    b[:, diag, diag] = M
    return b
```

where the timing shows this is approximately 4X faster:

```
M = np.random.random((1000, 3))
%timeit sol0(M)
#10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop
%timeit sol1(M)
#10000 loops, best of 3: 23.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: On my data with millions of rows the difference is not huge but it is still slightly faster, I will mark your answer as the accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: @KelSolaar which version of NumPy are you using? There was a significant in fancy indexing with version 1.9.0

Comment: 1.8.1 at the moment, most likely the reason why the speed gain is less than with your own tests.

Comment: Good to see a quicker method (+1)! It's just a slight improvement for me too on 1.8.0: time for me to upgrade my NumPy version...

Comment: On numpy 1.8 you will probably get more bang for the buck using slicing: `b = np.zeros((M.shape[0], M.shape[1]*M.shape[1])); b[:, ::M.shape[1]+1] = M; return b.reshape(M.shape[0], M.shape[1], M.shape[1])`. In 1.9 the difference with Saullo's answer are very small, although it is a tad faster for very large arrays.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one way using element-wise multiplication of `np.eye(3)` (the 3x3 identity array) and a slightly re-shaped `M`:

```
>>> M = np.random.rand(5, 3)
>>> np.eye(3) * M[:,np.newaxis,:]
array([[[ 0.42527357,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.17557419,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.61920924]],

       [[ 0.04991268,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.74000307,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.34541354]],

       [[ 0.71464307,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.11878955,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.65411844]],

       [[ 0.01699954,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.39927673,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.14378892]],

       [[ 0.5209439 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.34520876,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.53862677]]])
```

(By "re-shaped `M`" I mean that the rows of `M` are made to face out along the z-axis rather than across the y-axis, giving `M` the shape `(5, 1, 3)`.)

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I wanted, more than 7 times faster in my use case.